# Zoom into MKMapItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I need to zoom into a MKMapItem that is passed with a NSNotification and handled like so:

```
-(void)zoomToAnnotation:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Zoom into the passed MKMapItem
MKMapItem *passedMapItem = notification.object;
// self.previewMapView is the what I called my mapView
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
-(void)zoomToAnnotation:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Zoom into the passed MKMapItem
NSLog(@"beginCam");
MKMapItem *passedMapItem = notification.object;

MKMapCamera *mapCamera = [[MKMapCamera alloc] init];
mapCamera.centerCoordinate = [[passedMapItem placemark] coordinate];
[self.previewMapView setCamera:mapCamera animated:YES];
NSLog(@"endCam");
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

[image]

How can I zoom into a single MKMapItem using a MKMapView?

Thanks!

Comment: would `setCamera:Animated:`  passing the MKCamera parameter with a `centerCoordinate` with a coordinate coming from the annotation? Or something conformating to the `MKAnnotation` protocol?

Comment: @LouisTur thought of something similar myself, but I don't know how to get the coordinate of the MKMapItem.

Comment: looks like you need to access the `placemark` property which is an `MKPlacemark` class which conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol, meaning you can call it's `coordinate` property

Comment: @LouisTur Seems to freeze during setCamera:animated, see my update. It logs "beginCam" but not "endCam" and the simulator UI gets frozen. Any ideas for that?

Comment: update and put a breakmark after the line `MKMapItem * passedMapItem  = (MKMapItem *)notification.object` and make sure that it's actually a MKMapItem. Also, log out what `notification.object` is... or maybe if wrap it all in a conditional: `if([notification.object respondsToSelector:@selector(openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:){ } `

Comment: @LouisTur Looks like it's a MKMapItem - though it says" (int)" - what's that? See update 2

Comment: means it's likely not a MKMapItem, even though we're trying to typecast is as such. At that same breakpoint, what does it list notification.object as? What does your code for the notification look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69002/discussion-between-louis-tur-and-erik).

Answer (score 0):

(Copied from chat message, and a little quick n' dirty):

So, we were a bit off. Though I got it working via the following:

```
-(void)zoomToAnnotation:(NSNotification *)notification {

    MKMapItem *passedMapItem = (MKMapItem *)notification.object;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateOfInterest = passedMapItem.placemark.coordinate;

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinateOfInterest, MKCoordinateSpanMake(.1, .1));
    [self.previewMapView setRegion:region
                          animated:YES];

    [self.previewMapView addAnnotation:passedMapItem.placemark];
}

//in my implementation, I just have a random button call this
-(void) makeNotification{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateOfInterest = self.locationManager.location.coordinate;
    MKPlacemark * placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinateOfInterest 
                                                    addressDictionary:nil];

    MKMapItem * mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"mapPoint"
                                                        object:mapItem ];
}
```

So I guess the biggest take aways were that the MKCamera object isn't intended to be used to change the view of the map view, at least in the way we were trying. And ultimately, calling `setRegion:animated:` is what end up zooming in on a region in this case. I also had `setCenterCoordinate:animated:` implemented, but I look it out as it didn't seem to effect the end results we were hoping to acheive.

Additionally, location data needs to be provided via a `CLLocationManager`, which in iOS requires two (lightly documented) actions:

1. Add two properties to the projects plist: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` along with a string description. (see [this link for further info](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/))
2. Prompt user to allow for notification services via `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`

At any rate, I find the google maps API way easier to use in this respect, so I may just go back to using that. But good to figure this out, nonetheless.

good luck with the rest!